# How to keep line breaks in

Tags: environments, tcolorbox

I am trying to define custom environment for custom DSL and wrote

```
% Preamble
\documentclass[11pt]{article}


% Packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{width=0.9\textwidth,boxrule=0pt,colback=blue,arc=0pt,auto outer arc,left=0pt,right=0pt,boxsep=5pt,fontupper=\color{yellow}}


\newenvironment{code}
{
    \fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont
    %\textcolor{yellow}
    %\colorbox{BlueViolet}

    \begin{tcolorbox}

}
{
    \end{tcolorbox}
}


% Document
\begin{document}


    Example program:

    \begin{code}
        print("Hello world");
        exit(0);
    \end{code}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the code in `code` environment doesn't keep line breaks.

Comment: Put a \\ in your code:  print("Hello world");\\

Answer (score 9):

You are using a "normal" tcolorbox to show code. In this case, you text behavies like in `.tex` files, which means that a new line need an empty line between paragraphs or `\\`.

In any case I suggest to use a `tcblisting` box which is defined to use `listings` package (you can also use `minted`). In this case every line of code is shown into a different line.

```
% Preamble
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
    codestyle/.style={width=0.9\textwidth,boxrule=0pt,colback=blue,arc=0pt,auto outer arc,left=0pt,right=0pt,boxsep=5pt,fontupper=\ttfamily, colupper=yellow}
    }


\newtcolorbox{code}{codestyle}

\newtcblisting{codelisting}{listing only, codestyle}

% Document
\begin{document}


    Example program:

    \begin{code}
        print("Hello world");
        
        exit(0);
    \end{code}

\begin{codelisting}
print("Hello world");
exit(0);
\end{codelisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have used plenty of things I need to learn before I can understand your answer :)

Comment: So my trivial answer done in a comment is neat and clear?